# Taking all of the child keys in a section of my Firebase Database and displaying on a tableview

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create an array from a list of children keys from my firebase database. I can pull the data, insert it into an array, and print it to the console but it will not display in my table view. I've made sure the tableview is connected to the controller and the cells match. Here is my code and database structure.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class TeamDataSegueViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var ageListTable: UITableView!

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var ageList = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataObserver()

        self.ageListTable.delegate = self
        self.ageListTable.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func dataObserver() {
        ref.child("Database").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                self.ageList.append(snap.key)
                print(self.ageList)
                print(snap.key)
            }
        })
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return ageList.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = ageListTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        cell?.textLabel?.text = ageList[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }
}
```

I cant figure out how to show it but this is pretty much it. I want to be able to take all of the age groups and list them in a tableview i.e. age_group1, age_group2.

```
 - 504
     - Database
         - age_group1
             - count
         - age_group2
             - count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the table's data after you finished populating the array, i.e.

```
func dataObserver() {
    ref.child("Database").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            self.ageList.append(snap.key)
            print(self.ageList)
            print(snap.key)
            self.ageListTable.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I know i used to have it before I was able to pull the data correctly and display it in the console but it must have gotten removed when I tried to redo it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to convert each one of your snapshots into a dictionary, and pull the values out, something like this:

```
    for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot

            if let childDic = FIRSnap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                //do something with this dictionary
            }

            self.ageList.append(snap.key)
            print(self.ageList)
            print(snap.key)
        }
```